# linguagem C - Erro quando utiliza scanf em loop para obter dados do tipo inteiro e string

Tags: c, loop, scanf

A princípio estava tentando fazer uma árvore binária que receba valores do tipo intiro e string(nome e sobrenome). Mas colocarei somente um erro para resolver primeiro.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    
    int key, key2;
    char name[50], name2[50]; 

    printf("digite a chave: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("digite o nome: ");
    scanf("%50[^\n]s", name);
    
    printf("digite a chave: ");
    scanf("%d", &key2);
    printf("digite o nome: ");
    scanf("%50[^\n]s", name2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

O código compila, mas no momento em que alimento com os dados ocorre esse erro:

```
digite a chave: 12

digite o nome: digite a chave:
```

Logo depois encerra.
Poderia usar o for, mas fiz assim para ficar mais fácil de visualizar.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!

É bom lembrar que `'\n'` é o **caracter** de quebra de linha, inserido quando se aperta a tecla ENTER. Assim, é bom lembrar que as variáveis `key` e `key2` são do tipo **inteiro**, então não irão guardar um caracter.
Dessa forma, quando você escreve lê `key`, por exemplo, com `scanf("%50[^\n]", key);` você está lendo 50 caracteres, no máximo, (ou) até chegar em um `'\n'`.
Como variáveis inteiras não leêm `'\n'`, este caracter fica ali na linha para a próxima leitura de caracteres ou strings. E quando `key` vai guardar seu valor, logo se depara com `'\n'`, que você determinou sendo a parada de leitura. Então ele segue o algoritmo, pedindo a próxima chave.

Para resolver o problema, você têm dois modos:
•Você pode criar uma variável lixo, do tipo caracter, para ler o aquele `'\n'`, após a leitura de uma chave.
•Ou você poder inserir o seguinte código, para ler o nome e sobrenome: `scanf("\n%50[^\n]s", name);`, que já quebra linha, anulando aquele `'\n'` restante e liberando uma linha limpa, para a string `key` ler normalmente.

---

Caso não tenha vá continuar sem uma estrutura de repetição em se código, deixarei as duas formas de soluções aqui. Se for utilizar um `for`, `while` ou outro tipo de loop, acredito que com a explicação dada você consegue solucionar o problema em seu código, agora.

```c
//Utilizando uma variável lixo
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    
    int key, key2;
    char name[50], name2[50];
    char trash;

    printf("digite a chave: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    scanf("%c", &trash);
    printf("digite o nome: ");
    scanf("\n%50[^\n]s", name);
    
    printf("digite a chave: ");
    scanf("%d", &key2);
    scanf("%c", &trash);
    printf("digite o nome: ");
    scanf("\n%50[^\n]s", name2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

```c
//Utilizando a quebra de linha direto no scanf()
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    
    int key, key2;
    char name[50], name2[50]; 

    printf("digite a chave: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("digite o nome: ");
    scanf("\n%50[^\n]s", name);
    
    printf("digite a chave: ");
    scanf("%d", &key2);
    printf("digite o nome: ");
    scanf("\n%50[^\n]s", name2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Espero ter ajudado. Bons estudos!